# Copy/Cut Photos form gallery (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, gallery

I want to start develop an android application that one of the function will cut (copy if cutting is not possible) an image by date and time to another folder.

What i need to do and not success until now:

1. Access to the photos camera directory.
   I tried with the following command, but i got an empty directory:

> Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)

2. Scanning all files in the camera folder by a preset time.
3. Move the relevance photos to another folder.

Thanks.

Comment: I think your question is a little ambiguous, you need to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @JoxTraex I updated the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your work need huge amount of code.

But, i give you some hint. (not full answer)

(I'm in the Mobile, so i can't link on each class. I think you can search that api in Google)

1. Scan All Folder and Image

You may use 'MediaStore' api to query Media Data

Here's the example that i already implemented.

[Scan Image Folder](https://github.com/WindSekirun/NaraePicker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/windsekirun/naraepicker/AlbumActivity.java)

[Scan Image File](https://github.com/WindSekirun/NaraePicker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/windsekirun/naraepicker/ImageActivity.java)

2. Cutting Image

You have 2 choice of this function.

Easy Way: Using Image Editor Api in Adobe CreativeSDK. it's free.

Advanced Way: Using Image Cropper library such as [this](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/README.md)

Either two way are easy-to-use. Please check both of them.